# ERROR: /var/lib is world writable!

Tags: ubuntu

When I enter the command `sudo ufw status` in Ubuntu, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: /var/lib is world writable!
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What are /var/lib's permissions?  For that matter, what are /var's?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo chmod 755 /var/lib` will ensure that /var/lib has the right permissions.

Comment: but still gives same error